# I am trying to fetch position from my CCXT bybit account but there is nothing return

Tags: ccxt, bybit

Here is my request. To try and fetch data from my account position

```
import ccxt
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
from pprint import pprint

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

exchange = ccxt.bybit({
    'apiKey': '****',
    'secret': '******',
    })



markets = exchange.load_markets()
symbol = 'BTCUSDT'
market = exchange.market(symbol)

print(exchange.fetchPositions(symbol))
time.sleep(1234)
```

Was expecting to return a list of postion data

But it returned nothing